# Show that the conclusion may fail if the condition: $\lim \int f_n \, d\mu\lt +\infty$ is dropped.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose that  $(f_n)\in M^+(X, X)$ and $(f_n)$ converges to $f$, and that $$\int f \, d\mu=\lim \int f_n \, d\mu\lt +\infty,$$ we have the conclusion that $$\int_E f \, d\mu=\lim \int_E f_n \, d\mu$$ for each $E\in X$

Note that $M^+(X, X)$ denote the collection of all extended real-valued $X$-measuable functions on $X$

I already know how to prove the above claim, but could someone **show that the conclusion may fail if the condition: $\lim \int f_n \, d\mu\lt +\infty$ is dropped.** Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$ f_n = \chi_{[-n,0]} + \chi_{[n,n+1]},f = \chi_{]-\infty,0]}
$$
then $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and $\int f\,d\lambda = \lim \int f_n\,d\lambda$. (Here $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$).

But if you choose $E = [0,\infty[$...

Comment: Thanks, so if the functions are defined in this way, does it mean that $\lim \int f_n\,d\lambda = +\infty$? Also, could you explain further what happens when $E = [0,\infty)$?

Comment: @user3029 $\int_E f_n\,d\lambda = 1$ for all $n$, while $\int_E f\,d\lambda = 0$. To see this, try writing out the explicit expression for $\int_E f_n\,d\lambda$.